# Display runtime error message on specific line in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, assert

I would like to display custom error message during runtime in Xcode in C/C++ code. This could be used for example for custom assert() function.

I would like to display message inline, like SenTestingKit does:

[image: SenTestingKit]

Right now the only thing I can do is use `__builtin_trap` to stop at the correct line. But no custom error message is displayed.

[image: __builtin_trap]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try providing more information or examples.

Comment: Would a permanent message be ok ? If so, use #pragma message(your message here from the assert), and raise SIGTRAP or use __builtin_trap on that line.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with xcode but here's how it's done almost everywhere else.
Your custom assert will look like this:

```
#define MY_ASSERT(a1, a2, desc, ...) {\
     PrintAssertMessage(...);         \  
     DebugBreak();                    \
}
```

In windows there's already a DebugBreak function in win32 API.
In Linux and most other systems that run IA32/X64 you can simply call int 3 which is the breakpoint trap.

```
asm  ("int 3");
```

I read that in xcode it's:

```
__asm {int 3}
```

or

```
__asm__("int $3")
```

or

```
__asm__("trap")
```

In any case this should be surrounded by a macro that disables the assert in debug builds as well macro that defines how to cause a break point.

Comment: There is even ready-to-use function (`__builtin_trap`) that works like a crossplatform trap. And sure, you can add messagebox or console output. But this *doesn't* answer an original question, that is how to display this message inline in Xcode.